# Application of Ito formula to $\exp(-\int_t^T f(t,u)du)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Could someone verify whether I have correctly applied Ito's formula in this case? The underlying topic of this is HJM drift conditions for Zero Coupon Bond prices, but this should be irrelevant.

Let $I(t,T) = -\int_t^T f(t,u)du$. Also let $d f(t,T) = \alpha(t,T)dt + \sigma(t,T) dW(t)$ for some deterministic function $\alpha, \sigma$ and a 1-d Brownian motion $W(t)$ on some underlying probability space which should be irrelevant. Applying Ito's formula on $ P(t,T) = \exp(I(t,T))$ I get

$$d P(t,T) = P_tdt + P_IdI(t) + \frac{1}{2}P_{II} d \langle I \rangle$$

where $\langle \cdot \rangle$ denotes the quadratic variation operator. Is my derivation below correct:

$$ d P(t,T) = P(t,T) f(t,t) dt - P(t,T)f(t,T)dt + \frac{1}{2} P(t,T) \sigma^2(t,T)dt$$

i.e. are my calculations

$$ d I(t) = -f(t,T)dt$$

$$ d \left< I(t) \right> = d \left< \int_0^t \sigma(u,T) dW(u), \int_0^t \sigma(u,T) dW(u), \right>  =  d \int_0^t \sigma^2(u,T) d \left< W(u), W(u) \right>  = d \int_0^t \sigma^2(u,T) d u = \sigma^2(t,T) dt$$

correct ? I believe I have a mistake in the $dI(t)$ calculation, but I'm not sure what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it is $I(t,T) = -\int_t^{T} f(t,u)du$ and not $-\int_0^T f(u,T)du$?

Comment: @Mick yes: it is the way I wrote it down. I may have spotted my mistake, but I will update the question later: my $dI(t,T)$ is definitely wrong though.

Comment: Well if it was $I(t) = - \int_t^T f(u,T)du$ then $dI(t) = f(t,T)dt$, but it's $I(t) = -\int_t^T f(t,u)du $, where $dI(t)$ is something else.